# Is it possible to add a horizontal scrollbar to a tkinter.ttk Combobox?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm making a list of countries that you can choose from and some of them are too (horizontally) long.

```py
selected = StringVar()
mystyle = ttk.Style()
mystyle.theme_use('clam')

bigfont = Font(family="Helvetica",size=20, weight='bold')
root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Font", bigfont)

mystyle.configure('box.TCombobox', foreground='black', textsize=10, arrowsize=30, font='Helvetica 44 bold', background=gold, fieldbackground=gold, selectedbackground=gold)

mylb = ttk.Combobox(extras, textvariable=selected, values=countries, width=20, state="readonly", style='box.TCombobox', font='Helvetica 20 bold')
mylb.current(0)
mylb.grid()
```

I've googled about but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add a horizontal scrollbar to a tkinter.ttk Combobox?

No, it is not.

All of the available options for a combobox are documented in the tcl/tk man pages. The documentation is complete, so if scrolling isn't documented then it isn't available. You can read the man page [here](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The following can do this by modifying the popdown that is created internally by Tk to add a horizontal scrollbar when the popdown list is first mapped on screen. As this is working with the Tk internals this may be subject to change without notice. More checking of the Tk provided children would help make it more robust.

The result on Linux is shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

```
"""
Make a combobox with horizontal and vertical scrollbars
"""

import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Combobox(ttk.Combobox):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super(Combobox, self).__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.bind_class('ComboboxPopdown', '<Map>', self.on_map, add='+')

    def on_map(self, ev):
        """Tk internally creates the combobox popdown as a toplevel and we can bind
        to the Map event for this widget.
        Modify the popdown to add a horizontal scrollbar on first map event."""
        widgetname = ev.widget

        script = f'set frame {widgetname}.f'
        script += '''
            if {[llength [winfo children ${frame}]] < 3} {
                ttk::scrollbar ${frame}.hs -orient horizontal \
                    -command [list ${frame}.l xview]
                ${frame}.l configure -xscrollcommand [list ${frame}.hs set]
                grid ${frame}.hs -row 1 -column 0 -columnspan 2 -sticky news
            }
        '''
        self.tk.eval(script)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(App, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.combo = Combobox(frame, values=("ab " * 20, *dir(tk.Widget)))
        self.combo.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0)
        frame.place(relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)


def main(args=None):
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```